# add hyperlink to excel sheet with pandas, which references to a another sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have converted a pandas DataFrame to an Excel sheet using `df.to_excel`.

Now, I want to add hyperlinks to the values in one column. In other words, when a customer sees my excel sheet, he would be able to click on a cell and bring up another sheet on the excel document (i dont want to bring up a website !!)

Answer (score 4):

The fully reproducible example provided below demonstrates how you would create a workbook, in which you are able to click on a particular cell and bring up another sheet in the same excel document.

In this example we use [Xlswriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html) as the `engine=` parameter in `pandas.DataFrame.to_excel()`.  This done to make use of some methods in the worksheet class of Xlsxwriter library, including `worksheet.write_url()`([link to docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#write_url)).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Creating a dataframe 
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 2), columns=list('AB'))
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("test.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')

df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='data')

workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('sheetWithLink')

worksheet.write_url('A1',  'internal:data!A1')
worksheet.write('A1',  "A link to another sheet")


writer.save()
```

Expected Output:

[image]